# how to prove that one sequence is sub-sequence of another?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $a_n\:=\:\left(-1\right)^{\left[\frac{n}{3}\right]}$, $b_n\:=\:\left(-1\right)^n$.
Now, i see that $a_n$ is sub-sequence of $b_n$ . But how can i prove this?

**Edited:** $\left[x\right]$ meaning the floor function of x. take a look here :http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions

Comment: Notice that $b_n$ contains infinitely many $1$s and $-1$s.

Comment: @user121270 its not the question though..we all see that. how to prove is the question

Comment: Well, could you please describe how you see it?

Answer (score 4):

I've put the sequence $a_n$ in bold below within the sequence $b_n$.

$\mathbf{1},-1,\mathbf{1},-1,\mathbf{1},\mathbf{-1},1,\mathbf{-1},1,\mathbf{-1},\mathbf{1},-1,\mathbf{1},-1,\cdots$

More formally, since you have infinitely many $1$s and $-1$s available in $b_n$, you can find the sequence $a_n$ inside of it by simply selecting the next available $1$ or $-1$ that matches the term in $a_n$ you are looking for.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @TheBluegrassMathematician: Why not? It shows how to see the one sequence inside the other.

Comment: Not all proofs need to be formulas.

Comment: Maybe the boldface is not showing up well?

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip It took me a bit to see the pattern of in boldface; perhaps you could say "See that $a_n$ is marked in bold below."

Comment: I see your point but it would help to provide an explanation  for what you posted.

Comment: @anorton: okay, I will edit it!

Answer (score 3):

If you want a symbolic-looking and dignified proof, define

$$f(n) = \begin{cases} 2n & \text{when }a_n=1 \\ 2n+1 & \text{when }a_n=-1 \end{cases} $$

Then $f:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ is strictly increasing, and $(b_{f(n)})_n$ is therefore by definition a subsequence of $(b_n)_n$.

We also see that $b_{f(n)}=a_n$, by construction.

---

In every context that is not a beginners' classroom, however, it would be sufficient to observe that every possible value of $a_n$ occurs infinitely many times in $b_n$.

That this observation is enough can be proved rigorously along the above lines, by defining $f(n)$ recursively instead:
$$ \begin{align} f(0) &= \text{the least $n$ such that $b_n=a_0$} \\
f(k+1) &= \text{the least $n>f(k)$ such that $b_n=a_{k+1}$} \end{align} $$

Answer (score 2):

By putting $n_k=3k$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$ you have $$a_{n_k}=(-1)^{\left[\frac{3k}{3}\right]}= (-1)^k, \forall k\in \mathbb{N} $$ but this last equality is $b_n$ (just put $k=n$). This prove that $(b_n)_n=(a_{n_k})_k$ is a subsequence of $a_n$.

Comment: However, that was not the direction asked for in the question.

Comment: @HenningMakholm You're right, my mistake.